# In plotlyjs how to switch between shared yaxis to independent yaxis while using RangeSlider

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

Let's say I have a plot with three data traces which is plotted on a single plot with shared `xaxis` and `yaxis` along with a `rangeslider`. Now I want to switch this plot into a subplot plot using grid layout with 3 rows sharing the same `xaxis` and using different `yaxis` along with a `rangeslider`. Please check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/BaBMoKp) where I have these two plots.

I want to switch between the two modes[plot1 and plot2] of independent `yaxis` and shared `yaxis` respectively.

In the example, I am newly plotting both plots. But instead is there an approach where we can use `Plotly.relayout()` to achieve this switch.

The code form code pen is as below.

**HTML**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv">
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  </div>
  <div id="myDiv2">
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
// Plot 1 with shared x axes
var trace1 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 4,5],
  y: [10, 110, 120,34,56],
  yaxis: 'y1',
  type: 'line'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1,2,3],
  y: [100, 110, 120,97,28],  
  yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [1,2,3,4],
  y: [100, 1100, 200,45],
  yaxis: 'y3',  
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

var layout = {
  titiel:"Plot 1 with shared x axes with range slider",
  height:600,
xaxis:{rangeslider:{
  height: 200
}},
grid: {
    rows: 3, 
    columns: 1, 
    pattern: 'dependent',
    roworder: 'bottom to top'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true}, {responsive: true});

//plot2 with shared x and yaxes

var trace1 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 4,5],
  y: [10, 110, 120,34,56],
  // yaxis: 'y1',
  type: 'line'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1,2,3],
  y: [100, 110, 120,97,28],  
  // yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [1,2,3,4],
  y: [100, 1100, 200,45],
  yaxis: '',  
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

var layout = {
 title:"plot2 with shared x and yaxes with rangeSlider",
height:600,
xaxis:{rangeslider:{}},
grid: {
    rows: 3, 
    columns: 1, 
    pattern: 'dependent',
    roworder: 'bottom to top'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv2', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true}, {responsive: true});
```

**Expected:**
Switch between the two modes as shown in the image in an efficient manner without using a new plot.

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Your layout stays the same, it's your data that changes (yaxis fields), so it's `Plotly.restyle()` that seems appropriate for you. https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle

Comment: @DmitryShvedov Thanks a lot. Because of your comment I revisited the `Plotly.update()`. I initially tried it but it didn't work. But now I gave it careful read and the code works. :D I have created a new codepen where the last couple of line helps to toggle between this mode. [Working version](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/PooqPgO)

Comment: I had to use `plotly.update()` because there are changes in the layout as well. The number `grid` option of layout is necessary to intimate whether the plots are to laid out in multiple rows or as single row.